# How to set arrays values to ";" seperated value

Tags: javascript

I have an array which have value like this.

`a = ["Val1,Val2","Val3"]`

so technically it is like

`a[0] = "Val1,Val2"`
`a[1] = "Val3"`

When I am assiging to tag like this
`fTag.setAttribute('V', a);`

Here in this case I am getting like this
`<Tag V = Val1,Val2,Val3 ></Tag>`

I wanted to avoid this therefore I want to seperate through ";"

It will be look like

`<Tag V = Val1,Val2;Val3 ></Tag>`

So, How to seperate array value through ";".

Comment: maybe `.join(';')`?

Comment: @JaromandaX It works. Please answer so I can mark as answer

Comment: @shankysingh: It's right, seeing Jaromanda's answer only it clicked to me to use `Array.join`. Already it's answered and there will be no value addition to this questions. You can either delete this question(as it is very basic) or Accept any one's answer to close this question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JavaScript Array Join method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_join.asp)

```js
function myFunction() {
    var a = ["Val1,Val2","Val3"];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a.join(";");
    
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will accept your answer in sometime.

Comment: Can you elobrate what will be opposite of this

Comment: I mean if I have `Value = "Val1,Val2;Val3"` how to convert into an array

Comment: If you have `Value = "Val1,Val2;Val3"` as string. Then, you first need to split string with `;` as delimiter, which means, whereever `;` will occur, strings will be broken and stored as next element of `array`.
Now with `var arrayAfterSplit = Value.split(';');` you will have `arrayAfterSplit=["Val1,Val2", "Val3"];`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: @shankysingh: Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can join them using ";" using [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
let a = ["Val1,Val2","Val3"]

console.log(a.join(';'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to convert and flatten your array to convert Val1 and Val2 to individual array items (I separate the instruction for clarification):

```
var a = ["Val1,Val2","Val3"];

// convert
var convertedArray = a.map((x) => { return x.split(",") });

// flatten
var flattenArray = [].contact.apply([], convertedArray); // ["Val1", "Val2", "Val3"]

// join
var finalArray = flattenArray.join(";") // "Val1;Val2;Val3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the Arrays `join` method which will give you a string from an array separating all the single elements through a given separator. 
But it seems that inside your array you have an element which contains elements inside, separated by comma. 
So here both the cases depending on what you want to achieve:

```js
let a = ["Val1,Val2","Val3"];
// here you have the elements separated all by ;
console.log(a.join(';'));
// here you have all the elements and subelements separated by ;
console.log(a.join(',').replace(/,/g, ';'));
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the code try this out :

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
<p id="d"></p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
    var a = ["Val1,Val2","Val3"];

    var b = document.getElementById('d');
    b.innerHTML = a.join(';');
}
</script>
</html>
```

`